# How can I quickly find the determinant of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        14 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        31 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        26 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        10 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}
       =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        5\cdot2+1+3 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        5\cdot4+5+6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        5\cdot3+7+4 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        5\cdot1+3+2 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}$$$$
       =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        5\cdot2 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        5\cdot4 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        5\cdot3 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        5\cdot1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}
        +
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        5 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        7 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        3 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}
        +
        \begin{vmatrix}
        3 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        4 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        2 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

However I am not able to proceed beyond. The answer given is zero. Is there any simple determinant property that I am not able to guess?

Comment: Use better \cdot to indicate multiplication. For a moment I thought you have decimals there.

Comment: And you have a mistake at entry $\;a_{31}\;$ in your second determinant above: it should be $\;5\cdot\color{red}3+7+4\;$

Comment: @Timbuc how did you made that 3 red? Whars the markdown for that?

Comment: Between dollar signs, as usual, do \color{red}{...} , or whatever color you want.

Comment: ohh thats latex then, I thought markdown has such capability. So must not be available on stackoverflow/those that do not support latex

Comment: Apparently not, but I can't be sure. Anyway, stackoverflow definitely supports LaTeX (or MathJaX)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two last determinants in your right side are zero as they both have two equal columns, so you're left with:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
        14 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        31 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        26 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        10 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}=  \begin{vmatrix}
        5\cdot2 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        5\cdot4 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        5\cdot3 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        5\cdot1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}=  5\begin{vmatrix}
        2 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
        4 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
        3 & 3 & 7 & 4\\
        1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
        \end{vmatrix}=0
$$

Of course, much easier, short and clear, after you wrote your first equality sign, is to remark that the determinant is zero directly as

$$C_1=5C_2+C_3+C_4\;,\;\;C_i=i-\text{th column}$$

so that the matrix's rank isn't full and etc.

Comment: how is *the matrix's rank isn't full...*

Comment: @awellwisher because one of the columns is a linear combination of the other ones, thus its column rank $\;<4\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

You have found—and expressed it in the first equality—that the first column is a linear combination of other columns: $$Col_1 = 5\cdot Col_2+Col_3+Col_4$$ And the simple determinant property you can't guess is: determinant with linearly dependent columns is $0$ (and vice versa, if it is zero, it has linearly dependent columns—and rows, too).